# How to draw SVG lines inside HighCharts barcharts?

Tags: svg, highcharts, renderer

I have a grouped bar chart just like in http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-basic. I would like to draw horizontal lines with averages for each group (for example, historical world avg rainfall in Jan, Feb etc?) Is there a easy way to do it ? Ofcourse, each group would have different horizontal lines - but I couldn't figure out if there is a way to get handle to individual bars and do SVG lines or any other way. Much appreciate any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use loop to calculate average in each group and then translate position. Obviously you should need also information about tick width.

http://jsfiddle.net/rfwd9/2/

```
var i = 0,
            avg,
            yAxis = chart.yAxis[0],
            r = chart.renderer,
            tickWidth = chart.plotWidth / chart.series[0].data.length,
            startX = chart.plotLeft,
            len = chart.series[0].data.length,
            seriesCount = chart.series.length;


        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            avg = 0;
            $.each(chart.series, function (j, serie) {
                avg += serie.data[i].y;
            });
            avg = Math.floor(avg / seriesCount);

            r.path(['M', startX, chart.plotHeight -  yAxis.translate(avg), 'L', startX + tickWidth, chart.plotHeight - yAxis.translate(avg)])
                .attr({
                'stroke-width': 2,
                stroke: 'red'
            })
                .add();
            startX = startX + tickWidth;
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Sebestian! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that if the chart is resized, the lines are not redrawn and end up at the wrong places.